# How to assign an action when a local notification is shown in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How do I assign an action or execute code when a local notification is shown (not just tapped) in Swift? Currently I create the notification like this

```
var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
localNotification.alertAction = "Golie Report"
localNotification.alertBody = "Did you do what you could to meet your goal today?"
localNotification.fireDate = notifyTime
localNotification.category = "INVITE_CATEGORY";
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
```

and register it in AppDelegate.swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You cannot respond in *any* way when a local notification is *shown*. If the notification fires when your app is frontmost, you get an event (and the notification is not shown). But when the notification is merely *shown*, then you get nothing. Your app is not involved in any way. Your app is not even running. That is what a notification is: it is between the system and the user (and only optionally, since the user can turn off notifications, the device, and so on).